# vue.js pagination mis calculation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my app, I have some pagination code which calculates the pagination based on data from a REST API. When I add the page of pages, it is calculating from page 0 not from 1, so it says 0 of 9 and when it gets to the end it says 8 of 9, when it should say 1 of 9 and 9 of 9 at the end. So far my code is:

**HTML**

```
<p>Page {{page}} of {{pageCount}}</p>
```

**JS**

```
data: function() {
    return {
      page: 0
    };
  },

computed: {
    pageCount() {
      let l = this.result.length,
        s = this.size;
      return Math.floor(l / s);
    },
    paginated() {
      const start = this.page * this.size,
        end = start + this.size;
      return this.result.slice(start, end);
    }
  },
```

Any ideas? Maybe I am calculating the `math.floor` method wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like your pages are 0 indexed, not 1 indexed. The page count is correct, but you're starting from 0. Is there any reason you can't just add 1 on your view portion?

Comment: If I change `page: 1` the paginated results start from page 1

Comment: It will start from 1 of 9 but there is also results on the previous button for 0

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Vue, but anyway, what I'm suggesting is not to change the value of page: 0, but just what shows up to the user. <p>Page {{page + 1}} of {{pageCount}}</p> Would this work?

Comment: When I tried that before it did not work, but that has worked now, can you submit as answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page variable is 0 indexed instead of 1 index. You can keep it this way so that your pagination continues to work as intended, but where you are outputting it to the user you can simply add 1 so it makes sense to a user.

```
<p>Page {{page + 1}} of {{pageCount}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, your pageCount() method is correct because you indeed have 9 pages so math.floor is not the problem, your page variable is the one that is incorrect but I cannot see where you are getting that variable from but a simple yet coarse solution would be just to add 1 to the variable.